# Github Actions how to block merging other pull requests till master pipeline finished

Tags: github, github-actions

Basically I am trying to automate bumping up version in master pipeline.

Master pipeline should preform checks after merging pull request, bump up version and commit/push new version and tag to repository.

But if two developers merge two separated pull requests at the same time, master pipeline will not be able to increase versions for each merge separately. To avoid that problem I am looking for the way to block mergin pull request till the previous run of master pipeline finish.

Theoretically github merge queue might help to do something similar, however:

> Pull request merge queues are available in any public repository owned by an organization, or in private repositories owned by organizations using GitHub Enterprise Cloud.

Any other thoughts or suggestions how can that be implemented?

Comment: You might be able to use the `concurrency` keyword to make sure only one PR workflow runs at the same time. But it wouldn't solve out-of-order-merges. Updating filer in the workflow is something that's not recommended for there kinds of reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar idea, and have (mostly) achieved this with a bash script and a workflow that runs on pull requests. There are some caveats, which I'll detail below.  In my case, the version I was bumping lived in `_app-config.yml`, so you'll see that referenced in my scripts.

Here's the bash script I used to bump the version

```bash
#!/bin/bash

appConfig=./_app-config.yml

# Read the current version from the file
current_version=$(grep -Po '(?<=version: )[\d.]+(?=$)' $appConfig)

# Function to increment the version
bump_version() {
  local version=$1
  local IFS=.
  local parts=($version)
  local last_part=${parts[-1]}
  local new_last_part=$((last_part + 1))
  parts[-1]=$new_last_part
  new_version="${parts[*]}"
  echo "$new_version"
}

# Bump the version
new_version=$(bump_version $current_version)

# Replace the version in the file
sed -i "s/version: $current_version/version: $new_version/" $appConfig

# echo "Version bumped from $current_version to $new_version"
echo $new_version
```

Here's the workflow file

```yaml
name: Bump Version

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main

permissions:
  contents: write

jobs:
  bump_version:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Check for existing version change
        run: |
          git fetch origin main
          if [[ $(git diff --unified=0 origin/main HEAD -- _app-config.yml | grep version | wc -l) == 2 ]]; then
            echo "The 'VERSION' line has already been changed! We're done here."
            echo UPDATE_VERSION=false >> $GITHUB_ENV
          else
            echo "VERSION has not yet been updated, running bump_version script!"
            echo UPDATE_VERSION=true >> $GITHUB_ENV
          fi

      - name: Run bump_version.sh script
        if: env.UPDATE_VERSION == 'true'
        run: |
          chmod +x scripts/bump_version.sh
          echo NEW_VERSION=$(./scripts/bump_version.sh) >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Commit changes
        if: env.UPDATE_VERSION == 'true'
        run: |
          git config --local user.email "action@github.com"
          git config --local user.name "Bump Version GitHub Action"
          git add _app-config.yml
          git commit -m "Version incremented to $NEW_VERSION [no ci]"
          git push --force origin HEAD:${{github.event.pull_request.head.ref}}
```

What this does, is each pull request opened, and on each commit to them, this action runs & checks if the version has been updated.  It could be made smarter, but right now if `version` shows up in the `git diff` of the file in question, the workflow considers the changes to already be made.

If those changes aren't present, then the bash script parses the existing version & increments the patch version by one, and commits it back to the branch.

This works fairly well, although like I said this could be smarter, and its prone to bugs with pushing the wrong version or getting things out of order.  The bigger issue for me though, is that when the action pushes a commit, none of the other actions will run, so I have to `git commit -m'empty' --allow-empty && git push` in order for other tests to run.

Other than that, this has worked for me in a similar situation.  This isn't exactly what you're aiming for, but I hope that helps!